# Emacs cc-mode indentation problem with C++0x enum class

Tags: c++, emacs, enums, c++11, indentation

Emacs cc-mode does not appear to yet recognize the type-safe `enum class` introduced in C++0x. The result I get is a double indentation for second, third, etc enums:

```
enum class Color {
    Blue,
        Red,
        Orange,
        Green
        };
```

What I would like is:

```
enum class Color {
    Blue,
    Red,
    Orange,
    Green
};
```

Can you recommend a good command to add to `.emacs` which will make cc-mode treat `enum class` the same way it treats the plain old `enum`?

Comment: cc-mode does not really play well with C++0x.

Comment: This is one of the few issues with C++0x. I was planning on doing some ELISP work to correct this but I have no real need for it now. It shouldn't be hard the problem is that it sees enum and class as two keywords (which cant follow each other) which causes the double indentation.

Comment: Have you tried sending a bug report to <bug-cc-mode@gnu.org>?

Comment: I will now, thank you. But with this question, I'm looking for a temporary solution to add to `.emacs` until cc-mode is updated.

Comment: Which cc-mode style do you use?

Comment: Seems to me like adding `"enum class"` to line 1723 of `cc-langs.el.gz` (inside `(c-lang-defconst c-class-decl-kwds ...` might be the real fix)

Comment: I really mean line 1748, inside `(c-lang-defconst c-brace-list-decl-kwds ...`

Comment: Emacs 27 indents this correctly by default.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### This is the problem:

cc-mode relies somewhat on the assumption that keywords are single words. Adding support for `enum_class` instead of `enum class` would just be a matter of changing a few regexps.

Instead Emacs treats this as a class. The correct way of solving this would be teaching Emacs that this is an enum. But that's beyond the scope of an answer.

### This is the hack:

So we'll modify the existing indentation to behave differently in this one case. (Code available for tinkering in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2626303).)

```lisp
(defun inside-class-enum-p (pos)
  "Checks if POS is within the braces of a C++ \"enum class\"."
  (ignore-errors
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char pos)
      (up-list -1)
      (backward-sexp 1)
      (looking-back "enum[ \t]+class[ \t]+[^}]+"))))

(defun align-enum-class (langelem)
  (if (inside-class-enum-p (c-langelem-pos langelem))
      0
    (c-lineup-topmost-intro-cont langelem)))

(defun align-enum-class-closing-brace (langelem)
  (if (inside-class-enum-p (c-langelem-pos langelem))
      '-
    '+))

(defun fix-enum-class ()
  "Setup `c++-mode' to better handle \"class enum\"."
  (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(topmost-intro-cont . align-enum-class))
  (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist
               '(statement-cont . align-enum-class-closing-brace)))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'fix-enum-class)
```

This is not heavily tested. ;)

### How it works:

`c-offsets-alist` determines the indentation for different positions in the syntax tree. It can be assigned constants or functions.

These two functions find out whether the current position is *inside* the `enum class {...}`. If that's the case, they return 0 or '-, which cc-mode interprets as an indentation depth. If it isn't, they return the default value.

`inside-class-enum-p` simply moves up to the previous brace and checks if the text before it is "enum class".

Comment: Hi, could you provide a short high-level overview of what the hack is doing. In other words, how is it identifying this one special case? I'm slowly learning lisp, so I really appreciate excellent code like this as an opportunity to learn more.

Comment: Sure. I've added some documentation (and modified the code a bit).

Comment: There is one shortcoming: if your enum class has a trailing "," the closing "}" will not be properly indented.  For example, "enum class A { one=1,two=2,}"

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very good. I just have to replace the last "+" in the regexp by a "*" but someone wrote it on gist.

Comment: In case anybody else like me goes and tries to hack more on this snippet, the easiest way to get C++11 support is to make sure you're on Emacs 25.2 then manually install CC-Mode 5.33 which has C++11 support.

Comment: This hack is no longer needed in Emacs 27, which indents "enum class" correctly by default.