# Emacs indenting of C++11 lambda functions (cc-mode)

Tags: c++, c++11, emacs, indentation

The default Emacs C++ mode (`cc-mode`) still does not recognize many C++11 features.
One annoying issue is that it applies too much indentation to lambda functions used
as function parameters:

```
std::vector<int> ar(4);
std::generate_n(std::begin(ar), 4, [] {
        static int g_i;
        return g_i++;
    });
std::for_each(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), [](int i) {
        std::cout << " " << i;
    });
bool b = std::is_sorted(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), [&](int l, int r) {
        return l<r;
    });
std::cout << "   " << b << "\n";
```

Ideally, one would prefer:

```
std::vector<int> ar(4);
std::generate_n(std::begin(ar), 4, [] {
    static int g_i;
    return g_i++;
});
std::for_each(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), [](int i) {
    std::cout << " " << i;
});
bool b = std::is_sorted(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), [&](int l, int r) {
    return l<r;
});
std::cout << "   " << b << "\n";
```

Are there good solutions for this?

Comment: You should use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead of that `generate_n` call with the `static` variable.

Comment: Use dumber indenting.  Keep indent of previous line, use manual commands to backdent/indent.  At 1 key every fraction of a line cost, is it really worth maintaining and dealing with quirks of an entire code formatting code base?  I mean neat and all, and sometimes useful for copy/pasta...

Comment: @Praetorian It was intended as a quick example of a lambda function taking no arguments.  The `std::iota` function does not use a function parameter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The discussion in [Emacs cc-mode indentation problem with C++0x enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497374/) fixes the `enum class`
formatting issue.

This inspired the following advice function.  It detects an open C++ lambda function
in an open argument list, and cancels one level of indentation to produce the "ideal" result in the question:

```
(defadvice c-lineup-arglist (around my activate)
  "Improve indentation of continued C++11 lambda function opened as argument."
  (setq ad-return-value
        (if (and (equal major-mode 'c++-mode)
                 (ignore-errors
                   (save-excursion
                     (goto-char (c-langelem-pos langelem))
                     ;; Detect "[...](" or "[...]{". preceded by "," or "(",
                     ;;   and with unclosed brace.
                     (looking-at ".*[(,][ \t]*\\[[^]]*\\][ \t]*[({][^}]*$"))))
            0                           ; no additional indent
          ad-do-it)))                   ; default behavior
```

Comment: Should I be able to just add this to my .emacs to make it work?  It's exactly what I want, but no matter how I add it to my environment, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Mike Yes it should work as soon as the advice function is evaluated.  You could try invoking `(c++-mode)` on your active buffer to make sure it is in the correct major mode.  Also `(c-version)` should show the current cc-mode (for me it is 5.32.4).

Comment: See [frinkr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50755454/3084001) for the canonical solution in newer Emacsen.

Answer (score 19):

In Emacs26, the accepted answer doesn't work for me anymore. I just set the 'inlambda' to 0.

```
  (c-offsets-alist . ((case-label . 0)
                      (inline-open . 0)
                      (substatement-open . 0)
                      (inlambda . 0) ; no extra indent for lambda
                      (block-open . 0) ; no space before {
                      (knr-argdecl-intro . -)))
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Please also link to the documentation, specifically [`(ccmode) Statement Block Symbols`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/draft/manual/html_node/ccmode/Statement-Block-Symbols.html) and [`(ccmode) FAQ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/draft/manual/html_node/ccmode/FAQ.html).

Comment: Fixed link: [10.2.12 Statement Block Symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Statement-Block-Symbols.html) and [ccmode FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/FAQ.html)

Comment: For me, this yields `Symbol’s function definition is void: c-offsets-alist`

Answer (score 4):

A slight rework of the Hugues' solution to also recognize lambda function as an argument nested in another lambda function, and lambda function as an in-class initialization value:

```
(defun vr-c++-looking-at-lambda_as_param ()
  "Return t if text after point matches '[...](' or '[...]{'"
  (looking-at ".*[,(][ \t]*\\[[^]]*\\][ \t]*[({][^}]*?[ \t]*[({][^}]*?$"))

(defun vr-c++-looking-at-lambda_in_uniform_init ()
  "Return t if text after point matches '{[...](' or '{[...]{'"
  (looking-at ".*{[ \t]*\\[[^]]*\\][ \t]*[({][^}]*?[ \t]*[({][^}]*?$"))

(defun vr-c++-indentation-examine (langelem looking-at-p)
  (and (equal major-mode 'c++-mode)
       (ignore-errors
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (c-langelem-pos langelem))
           (funcall looking-at-p)))))

(defun vr-c++-indentation-setup ()
  (require 'google-c-style)
  (google-set-c-style)

  (c-set-offset
   'block-close
   (lambda (langelem)
     (if (vr-c++-indentation-examine
          langelem
          #'vr-c++-looking-at-lambda_in_uniform_init)
         '-
       0)))

  (c-set-offset
   'statement-block-intro
   (lambda (langelem)
     (if (vr-c++-indentation-examine
          langelem
          #'vr-c++-looking-at-lambda_in_uniform_init)
         0
       '+)))

  (defadvice c-lineup-arglist (around my activate)
    "Improve indentation of continued C++11 lambda function opened as argument."
    (setq ad-return-value
          (if (vr-c++-indentation-examine
               langelem
               #'vr-c++-looking-at-lambda_as_param)
              0
            ad-do-it))))
```